# How to avoid Memory "Hard Fault/sec"

Tags: performance, memory, performance-tuning

i've a problem on my windows 2008 server x64, and i cannot understand how can i solve it.

i'm looking to Resource Monitor and see about 100 to 200 hard faults/sec. and generally the machine is slow. As i've readed a bit it is caused by a "memory Page" that is no longer available on physical memory and causes a io operations (disk) and it is a problem.

The current hardware is a intel core2duo E8400 (3.0GHz) with 6GB RAM on a Windows Server Web 64-bit.

Actually the machine have about 2GB Ram used what having 4Gb available to use, Why is the machine requires that high level of Disk operations?

what can i do to increase the performance? Im experiencing a memory issues?

what should be my starting point?

Comment: Perhaps your paging file is too small, forcing windows to expel pages even when it has plenty of free memory.

Comment: Are you running any kind of "performance optimizer" or "memory optimizer"?